# Is this possible $(ap+bq)'(t) = (ap)'(t) + (bq)'(t)$, where the prime $'$ denotes differential?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Can $(ap+bq)'(t) = (ap)'(t) + (bq)'(t)$, where the prime denotes differential and $p$ and $q$ are polynomials and $a$ and $b$ are constants.
I am asking if the differential of $ap+bq$ with respect to $t$ is equal to the differential of $(ap)$ with respect to $t$ plus the differential of $(bq)$ with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 4):

The derivative is a *linear* operator. That is, if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions, and $c$ is a constant, then

$$(f + g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$$

and

$$(cf)'(x) = c f'(x)$$

It is instructive to prove this from the definition; in particular, it relies on the fact that the sum of limits is the limit of the sum under reasonable assumptions.

Comment: oh! okay thank you again T. Bongers